# How to return an array of two arrays in VBA function

Tags: arrays, vba

I like to have a function returning two arrays, each array 
composed of many small fixed size (2) arrays.

```
function AssbIO(...) as variant()
'...
Dim i() as variant
Dim o() as variant
Redim i(0 to 1) 
Redim o(0 to 1) 

i(0)(0)=1
i(0)(1)=2

i(1)(0)=3
i(1)(1)=4

o(0)(0)=11
o(0)(1)=22

o(1)(0)=33
o(1)(1)=44

'Now the following is giving me an error
AssbIO(0) = i
AssbIO(1) = o

End Function
```

Your help would be appreciated.

PS. Here is the full Program i am trying to achieve
Given a series of i and o, i want to construct a series
of i's (from 1 to 4, then from 7 to 9...)
and of o's (from 5 to 6, then from 10 to 15)
Example: IO=("i","i","i","o","o","i")
then i=((1,3),(6,6)) and o=((4,5))

```
Function AssbIO(IO() As String) As Variant

Dim i() As Variant
Dim o() As Variant
Dim ni As Integer 'the jumper of i()
Dim no As Integer 'the jumper of o()
Dim nIO As Integer ' the jumper of initial IO()
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer 
a = 1

While nIO <= erLen(IO)
  b = a 

  While IO(nIO) = "i"
   b = b + 1
   nIO = nIO + 1
  Wend

    ni = ni + 1
    ReDim Preserve i(0 To ni - 1)
    i(ni - 1)(0) = a
    i(ni - 1)(1) = b
    a = b + 1

  While IO(nIO) = "o"
   b = b + 1
   nIO = nIO + 1
  Wend

    no = no + 1
    ReDim Preserve o(0 To no - 1)
    o(no - 1)(0) = a
    o(no - 1)(1) = b
    a = b + 1

 While IO(nIO) <> "i" And IO(nIO) <> "n"
 nIO = nIO + 1
 Wend

Wend

'ReDim AssbIO(0 To 1) 'this is giving me errors
AssbIO(0) = i
AssbIO(1) = o

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for the *specific* question, use a Variant array as an *"intermediate"*:

```
Dim var(0 To 1) As Variant

    ....

    ni = ni + 1
    ReDim Preserve i(0 To ni - 1)
    var(0) = a
    var(1) = b
    i(ni - 1) = var
    a = b + 1
```

you may also want to consider the following refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Function AssbIO(IO() As String) As Variant
    Dim i() As Variant, o() As Variant
    Dim ni As Long 'the jumper of i()
    Dim no As Long 'the jumper of o()
    Dim iIo As Long
    Dim strng As String        
    Dim var(0 To 1) As Variant

    ni = -1
    no = -1        
    iIo = LBound(IO)
    Do While iIo <= UBound(IO)
        strng = IO(iIo)
        If strng = "i" Then
            UpdateArr IO, i(), ni, strng, iIo
        ElseIf strng = "o" Then
            UpdateArr IO, o(), no, strng, iIo
        Else
            iIo = iIo + 1
        End If
    Loop

    var(0) = i
    var(1) = o
    AssbIO = var
End Function


Sub UpdateArr(IO() As String, arr() As Variant, nArr As Long, strng As String, iIo As Long)
    Dim b As Long, incIO As Long
    Dim var(0 To 1) As Variant

    b = iIo
    incIO = incIO + 1
    Do While iIo + incIO <= UBound(IO)
        If IO(iIo + incIO) <> strng Then Exit Do
        b = b + 1
        incIO = incIO + 1
    Loop
    var(0) = iIo
    var(1) = b

    nArr = nArr + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To nArr)
    arr(nArr) = var

    iIo = iIo + incIO
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks user3598756! so an INTERMEDIATE variant was necessary to pass the values of those 2 arrays to the function-answer. Also thanks for the reworking of my code (mine uses pre made function...). I will study your code in depth tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why you wouldn't just define a two-dimensional array (which would suit you well if you have a genuine 2x2 matrix). However, if you want nested or jagged arrays, then you can either dimension some variants and add them to your final array or use the `Array()` function containing nested arrays.

The code below gives you three ways of doing the nested array method:

```
Function AssbIO() As Variant

    'Option1 - just write directly to arrays
    Dim result1 As Variant
    result1 = Array(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4)), Array(Array(11, 22), Array(33, 44)))

    'Option2 - create empty nested arrays, then populate line by line
    Dim result2 As Variant
    result2 = Array( _
              Array(Array(Empty, Empty), Array(Empty, Empty)), _
              Array(Array(Empty, Empty), Array(Empty, Empty)))

    result2(0)(0) = 1
    result2(0)(1) = 2
    '...etc.

    'Option3 - dimension all the arrays
    Dim result3(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim o(0 To 1) As Variant
    result3(0) = i
    result3(1) = o

    result3(1)(0) = 3
    result(1)(1) = 4

    'Return your result
    AssbIO = result1 'or 2 or 3
End Function
```

Comment: Dear Ambie, thanks for your answers, but i am really working with undefined size i() and o(), so AssbIO should be dynamic also... I will edit the answer soo to reflect my true needs